# Extra wires and jacks on my chandelier - where do they go?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Can someone help me understand why my chandelier has a positive, negative and ground wire, then something I've never seen: 2 sets of blue and white wires and 2 jack holes inside connection pad? I'm assuming they go inside the jacks for over heating but I'm not an electrician.

Thanks in advance,
Francesco

[image][image]

Comment: if it's a 2-bulb chandelier (or a 2 cluster) then there is a set of wires to each bulb (cluster)

Comment: We need another view of the fixture.  As posted it’s not possible to know if there’s one bulb or twenty.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where did this fixture come from? Did it come with instructions?

Answer (score 1):

The black, white and green/bare are for you to connect.

The blue/white are internal to the appliance to route the current to the various place it is needed (each bulb). It's got nothing to do with over-heating.

Answer (score 1):

That [Eurofase F-20KAS2-05](https://www.1800lighting.com/Eurofase-Lighting/Kasper/item.cfm?itemsku=F-20KAS2-05) fixture uses low-voltage halogen light bulbs.
This means that somewhere hidden in that big cover is a power supply - that's where the blue wires go.
The blue wires are connected to the white wires (which run down the shaft to the light bulbs) with those white crimped-on caps. These are not intended to be fiddled with by the user/installer - they're permanent & non-removable.
The only wires you need to concern yourself with are the black/white/ground wires which supply power to the hidden low-voltage power supply - black to hot, white to neutral, ground to ground.